# Xcode Authentication failed because no credentials were provided after changing iOS version to 14

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I changed my app deployment version from iOS 13 to iOS 14 and I am getting an error building the app.

[image]

It keeps talking about no credentials provided although all these packages are public. Also I have github credentials set up and use them all the time.

I have tried removing github account, changing ssh -> http, but nothing seems to help.

Same issue happens when I try to add a new public package using Swift Package Manager

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Check your git config file first write your terminal: `git config --global --edit`

and it is supposed to be there `"https://github.com/:` rather than `url.git@github.com.`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, the error I was receiving was:

> xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
> **Authentication failed because the credentials were missing.**
> artifact not found for target 'AddonManager'.

The solution was to generate my SSH key using RSA instead of Ed25519, it seems like Xcode couldn't read my SSH key in the Ed25519 format.

I re-generated my SSH using the *legacy* RSA algorithm ([as noted in the github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)) and added it to my local machine, this fixed the error on the next build.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent